# How to handles routes with Angular and Electron

Tags: angular, electron

I have added an electron configuration to an existing SPA application. When i click a link in the navbar, I get the following error:

```
 /dist/about net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I know there is no such file in the directory, but I have been looking for a while now on how to deal with routes.

Currently I have found nothing but boilerplate projects with only one page, and I'm starting to think routes are not possible in Electron(if not, please let me know).

Feel free to check out my [source code](https://github.com/seel93/Angular5_MdBoot). I am currently using the electron documentation boilerplate in my `main.js` file.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `href` in the navBar to: `#<componentName>` fixed the issue. 
Example:

```
<li class="nav-item waves-light" mdbRippleRadius>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an AppRoutingModule which you can import into the import array in **App.Module.ts**, then inside of **app.routing.module.ts** (which @angular/cli asks if you want to include upon installation) create something like the following,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pageOne', component: PageOneComponent},
  { path: 'pageTwo', component: PageTwoComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/pageOne', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

so the 1st and 2nd "path" point to the pages/components you wish to route to, whereas the 3rd one is a default "landing page" for your app, and the last one is what gets displayed when an invalid route is accessed.
Needless to say these components including the page-not-found component have to exist and be imported inside of the **app.routing.module.ts**.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Also add the above code after the routes array.
To access any one of these routes, simply use an anchor/button such as `<a routerLink="/pageOne">Go To Page One</a>`